# Use HDR environment map with Node materials

Tags: three.js

I have been using the usual THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial for years now but due to limitations, I am trying to move towards the node system which I guess will be the future.

Documentation about nodes is currently very limited and my only sources were the example on the threejs website and the node code in the Github repository.

Is it currently possible to use a HDR equirectangular environment map with Node.StandardNodeMaterial?

With the THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial workflow, I normally do the following -

1. Load the equirectangular HDR texture using EquirectangularToCubeGenerator, PMREMGenerator and PMREMCubeUVPacker
2. Assign the generated texture to the envMap input of THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial

For Node.StandardNodeMaterial, I only found the examples with the spherical environment map and the cube map:

```
mtl.environment = new Nodes.TextureNode( getTexture( "spherical" ), new Nodes.ReflectNode( Nodes.ReflectNode.SPHERE ) );

mtl.environment = new Nodes.CubeTextureNode( cubemap );
```

But I could not make that work with my HDR equirectangular texture processed by the PMREM generator.

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps_hdr_nodes.html, https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps_pmrem_nodes.html

Comment: Thanks and sorry for wasting your time. I just found the examples and it works perfectly. I may not have been awake this morning.